# Inox moka pot boiled without water

Tags: moka

Unfortunately, I put my new Bialleti inox moka pot to the fire without water. The bottom part inside is pretty black. I sould mention that it had already a layer of salt from the water in my area. I'm currently trying with water and vinegar but nothing happened. Should I add baking soda? Or what?

Comment: Do you mean literal sodium chloride salt or limescale?

Answer (score 1):

Too bad. However, if the black stuff you see is just a layer of burned salt, or whatever, you should be able to scrap it off with some iron wool.

It's possible, on the other hand, that it's not really black, rather dark violet. It's the color that inox steel gets after prolonged heating. In that case, it's completely innocuous and you can leave it there.

Comment: Thanks! It was burned salt. I didn't want to scrap it so I just soak it with water, vinegar and baking soda. I also replaced the rubber, and it's brand new (almost)... :)

Comment: Soaking with *both* vinegar and baking soda at the same time is useless, though it does make bubbles that make it *look like* it is doing something.  Whichever one you use most of will totally neutralize the other.